# Show that the matrix has determinant $=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider the matrix $M=$

\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\   
1&-1&1&1&1&0&0\\                                                                                                                  
1&1&-1&1&1&0&0\\                                                                                                                 
1&1&1&-1&1&0&0\\                                                                                                                
1&1&1&1&-1&0&0\\                                                                                                               
1&0&0&0&0&-3&1\\                                                                                                              
1&0&0&0&0&1&-3\\                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
\end{bmatrix}

> Show that $M$ has determinant $0$ and its rank is $6$.

In order to show that determinant of the matrix is $0$ we need to expand $M$ along the last row by Laplace Expansion which is cumbersome.

Are there any other methods to show that $M$ has determinant zero.

I have shown the second part that rank(M)=6 because we have the sub-matrix
\begin{bmatrix}
-1&1&1&1&0&0\\                                                                                                                  
1&-1&1&1&0&0\\                                                                                                                 
1&1&-1&1&0&0\\                                                                                                                
1&1&1&-1&0&0\\                                                                                                               
0&0&0&0&-3&1\\                                                                                                              
0&0&0&0&1&-3\\                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
\end{bmatrix}

which is block diagonal matrix and each of its block has non-zero determinant.

However how to show the first part? Is there any elegant way to show this as the matrix has a definite pattern?

Please help.

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/499321/350028).

Comment: $Mx=0$ has a nice non-trivial integer vector solution. It isn't hard to find that solution.

Comment: @user1551; will you please help on how to find it

Comment: @user1551; atleast give some hint on how to proceed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to do any tedious row/column operations. All you need is some simple inspection.

As $M$ is a $7\times7$ matrix of rank $\ge6$, if $\det M=0$, the null space of $M$ must be one-dimensional.

As you have shown, the last six columns of $M$ are linearly independent. Therefore, if $x=(a,b,c,d,e,f,g)^T\ne0$ lies in the null space of $M$, then $a$ must be nonzero. Also, by symmetry of coefficients in the last two rows/columns of $M$, if $M(a,b,c,d,e,f,g)^T=0$, then $M(a,b,c,d,e,g,f)^T$ must be zero too. It follows that if the null space of $M$ is indeed one-dimensional, we must have $f=g$.

So, by looking at the last two rows of the equation $M(a,b,c,d,e,f,f)^T=0$, we may assume that $f=1$ and $a=2$. The equation $M(2,b,c,d,e,1,1)^T=0$ then reduces to
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&1&1\\   
-1&1&1&1\\
1&-1&1&1\\
1&1&-1&1\\
1&1&1&-1\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}b\\ c\\ d\\ e\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}-4\\ -2\\ -2\\ -2\end{bmatrix},
$$
which is clearly solvable by $b=c=d=e=-1$. Hence $M(2,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1)^T=0$ and in turn $\det M=0$.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE:

After perforoming a row operation, it is easy for me to spot that 
$$
(2, -1,-1,-1,-1,1,1)
$$
is a nontirivial solution as @user1551 commented. Thanks for that hint.

Disclaimer: this method might not be elegant enough as you wanted.

**Solution**. $\blacktriangleleft$ Add the $(-1)$ $\times$ 1st row to  rows 2 thru 5, we have
$$
\det (\boldsymbol M) =: A =
\begin{vmatrix}
1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\
0&-2 &0 & 0 & 0 & -1 &-1\\
0& 0&-2 & 0 & 0 & -1 &-1\\
0& 0 &0 & -2 & 0 & -1 &-1\\
0& 0 &0 & 0 & -2 & -1 &-1\\
1& 0 &0 & 0 & 0 & -3 & 1\\
1& 0 &0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -3
\end{vmatrix},
$$
Now add the $(-1)$ $\times$ 1st column to the 6th and 7th column:
$$
A = \begin{vmatrix}
1&1&1&1&1&0&0\\
0&-2 &0 & 0 & 0 & -1 &-1\\
0& 0&-2 & 0 & 0 & -1 &-1\\
0& 0 &0 & -2 & 0 & -1 &-1\\
0& 0 &0 & 0 & -2 & -1 &-1\\
1& 0 &0 & 0 & 0 & -4 & 0\\
1& 0 &0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -4
\end{vmatrix}.
$$
Note that the right lower corner seems triangular, so we expand the determinant along the 1st column, then $A = A_1 - A_6 + A_7$ where the indices indicate the row.

$A_1$ is easy to calculate, since it is triangular, and we have $A_1 = 4^4 = 256$. For $A_6$:
$$
A_6 = 
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 &0\\
-2 &0 & 0 & 0 & -1 &-1\\
0&-2 & 0 & 0 & -1 &-1\\
0 &0 & -2 & 0 & -1 &-1\\
0 &0 & 0 & -2 & -1 &-1\\
0 &0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -4
\end{vmatrix}
=
-4\begin{vmatrix}
1&1&1&1&0\\
-2 &0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
 0&-2 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
 0 &0 & -2 & 0 & -1 \\
 0 &0 & 0 & -2 & -1 
\end{vmatrix}
$$

Add $1/2$ times rows of no. 2,3,4,5 to the 1st row:
$$
A_6 = 
-4\begin{vmatrix}
0&0&0&0&-2\\
-2 &0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
0&-2 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
0 &0 & -2 & 0 & -1 \\
0 &0 & 0 & -2 & -1 
\end{vmatrix}
=
8\begin{vmatrix}
-2 &0 & 0 & 0\\
0&-2 & 0 & 0  \\
0 &0 & -2 & 0\\
0 &0 & 0 & -2 
\end{vmatrix}
= 128.
$$
For $A_7$, 
$$
A_7 = 
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 &0\\
-2 &0 & 0 & 0 & -1 &-1\\
0&-2 & 0 & 0 & -1 &-1\\
0 &0 & -2 & 0 & -1 &-1\\
0 &0 & 0 & -2 & -1 &-1\\
0 &0 & 0 & 0 & -4 & 0
\end{vmatrix}
= 4
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
-2 &0 & 0 & 0 & -1\\
0&-2 & 0 & 0 & -1\\
0 &0 & -2 & 0 &-1\\
0 &0 & 0 & -2 &-1
\end{vmatrix}
= 4 \times (-32) = -128
$$
as calculated above. Hence $A = 256 - 128 + (-128) = 0$. $\blacktriangleright$

Answer (score 0):

Row reduction:
$$\begin{vmatrix}
1&1&1&1&1&1&1\\   
1&-1&1&1&1&0&0\\                                                                                                                  
1&1&-1&1&1&0&0\\                                                                                                                 
1&1&1&-1&1&0&0\\                                                                                                                
1&1&1&1&-1&0&0\\                                                                                                               
1&0&0&0&0&-3&1\\                                                                                                              
1&0&0&0&0&1&-3\\                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
\end{vmatrix}\stackrel{-C_1+C_6\to C6\\ \ 3C_1+C_7\to C_7}{=}
\begin{vmatrix}
1&1&1&1&1&0&4\\   
1&-1&1&1&1&-1&3\\                                                                                                                  
1&1&-1&1&1&-1&3\\                                                                                                                 
1&1&1&-1&1&-1&3\\                                                                                                                
1&1&1&1&-1&-1&3\\                                                                                                               
1&0&0&0&0&-4&4\\                                                                                                              
1&0&0&0&0&0&0\\                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
\end{vmatrix}=\\
\begin{vmatrix}
1&1&1&1&0&4\\   
-1&1&1&1&-1&3\\                                                                                                                  
1&-1&1&1&-1&3\\                                                                                                                 
1&1&-1&1&-1&3\\                                                                                                                
1&1&1&-1&-1&3\\                                                                                                               
0&0&0&0&-4&4\\                                                                                                              
\end{vmatrix}\stackrel{C_6+C_5\to C_5}{=}
\begin{vmatrix}
1&1&1&1&4&4\\   
-1&1&1&1&2&3\\                                                                                                                  
1&-1&1&1&2&3\\                                                                                                                 
1&1&-1&1&2&3\\                                                                                                                
1&1&1&-1&2&3\\                                                                                                               
0&0&0&0&0&4\\                                                                                                              
\end{vmatrix}=\\
4\begin{vmatrix}
1&1&1&1&4\\   
-1&1&1&1&2\\                                                                                                                  
1&-1&1&1&2\\                                                                                                                 
1&1&-1&1&2\\                                                                                                                
1&1&1&-1&2\\                                                                                                               
\end{vmatrix}\stackrel{C_1+C_2+C_3+C_4\to C_4}{=}
4\begin{vmatrix}
1&1&1&4&4\\   
-1&1&1&2&2\\                                                                                                                  
1&-1&1&2&2\\                                                                                                                 
1&1&-1&2&2\\                                                                                                                
1&1&1&2&2\\                                                                                                               
\end{vmatrix}=0$$