# How do you know if set of vectors will span a line, a plane, or all of ℝ3?

Tags: linear-algebra

I was given this question in an assignment asking if $u=(0,2,-2), v=(1,-2,1)$ and $w=(4,2,3)$ will span a line, a plane or all of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

What I have done so far is determined that these vectors are linearly independent by row reducing to calculate a diagonal product that is not equal to $0$, proving that it is not linearly dependent. This means that it is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$.

What I am confused about is how do I know whether this will span a plane, a line or $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Does a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$ imply it spans $\mathbb{R}^3$?

How do I know if a vector spans a plane or a line or $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  If three vectors are linearly independent, they will span a $3$-dimensional space

Comment: What is the definition of the span of a set of vectors? (Note that the question is not about the span of a single vector!)

Comment: A (linear) [span](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_span) of a set of vectors is the set of vectors that can be obtained by linear combinations of the vectors from the original set

Comment: @J.W.Tanner thanks! So to clarify, that means this will span all of R3, rather than a line or a plane? What would the process be if this was a plane or a line?

Comment: If you have three vectors, they could span a space of dimension $0$, $1$, $2$, or $3$; $3$ if they are linearly independent, otherwise less than $3$

Comment: The dimension of the span is the *rank* of the matrix of the vectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have $3$ linearly independent vectors, they will span a $3$-dimensional space.

If you have $3$ vectors that are linearly dependent, they will span a space of $0$, $1$, or $2$ dimensions.

Your vectors are independent, so they span $\mathbb R^3$.

Here is an example of three vectors that span a plane:  $(1,0,0), (0,1,0), (1,1,0)$.

Here is an example of three vectors that span a line:  $(1, 1, 0), (2,2,0), (3,3,0)$.

Here is an example of three vectors that span a zero-dimensional space:

$(0,0,0), (0,0,0), (0,0,0)$.

Comment: That clarifies everything. Thank you! So to my understanding, the vector set of (u,v,w) will span R3 because they are 3 linearly independent vectors. For a set of 3 vectors to span a plane, you need a missing pivot, and for it to span a line, the vectors will be multiples.

Comment: Yes, though I would write $\color{blue}{\{}u,v,w\color{blue}{\}}$ for a set of vectors

Answer (score 0):

Since we have that given $n$ vectors $v_{1}\cdots v_{n}$ $ \in \mathbb{K}^{n}$ these are linearly independant if and only if det$(v_{1} | \cdots | v_{n}) \ne 0$

(You can find some reference [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/499321/why-is-the-determinant-zero-iff-the-column-vectors-are-linearly-dependent))

We have that since $$\mbox{det}\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & 4 \\ 2 & -2 & 2 \\ -2 & 1 & 3\end{pmatrix} \ne 0$$

They are linearly independant, which means they span a subspace of dimension 3, but since the space is $\mathbb{R}^{3}$, span($u,v,w$) = $\mathbb{R}^{3}$.

Note that is determinant equals to $0$ it means that the vector are not linearly dependant, so they can span a plane (which is the case when just one of them is linearly depedent from the other two), or a line (when two of them linearly depend from a one of them).

Comment: Thank you for clarifying!

Comment: @Peter If it helped could you consider accepting the answer